# Return a constant text string for every row in a column (dynamic) SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, constant-expression

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

I use the following query

```
SELECT wh_id, item_number
FROM   table_1
```

To get a table result that looks like this

```
wh_id    item_number
  1        12341
  2        12342
  3        12343
  4        12344
```

My result needs to look like below where the value in the constant column are not really located anywhere in any table. Rather its returned dynamically regardless of how many rows are returned the result set always returns the text 'link' for every row.

```
wh_id    item_number   Constant
  1        12341         link
  2        12342         link
  3        12343         link
  4        12344         link
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT wh_id, item_number, 'link' as Constant
FROM   table_1
```